# wireshark doesn't display packets from pcap file

Tags: wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I have pcap file with packets captured from CentOS machine and now I am trying to open it in Mac. It says `packets 428 displayed 0`.

The reason I need to open it on Mac is there I have wireshark dissector plugin .so file which I could not make work on CentOS.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with version of Wireshark.
On Mac was using Wireshark 2.2.6 and on CentOS it was 1.8. Installed Wireshark 2.2.6 on CentOS as well.

Not sure why these were not compatible.